# For which value t is this function a scalar product?

Tags: matrices, vectors, inner-products

I need help with this problem:

Determine if for the real parameter t there are values for which the function $(x1, x2),(y1, y2)) → (x1, x2)$
$
\begin{pmatrix}  
6 & e^{2t} \\
2e^t-1 & 2 \\ 
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}
y1 \\
y2
\end{pmatrix}$ is a scalar product in in $R^2$ :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $t=0$. Here is why.

This matrix has to be 1) symmetric 2) positive definite, which amounts to say that

Point 1) $$2e^t-1=e^{2t} \ \ \Leftrightarrow  \ \ (e^t-1)^2=0 \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ e^t=1 \ \ \Leftrightarrow \ \ t=0$$

meaning that the matrix is necessarily $\pmatrix{6&1\\1&2}$. But is it positive definite ?

Point 2) Let us expand the matrix product :

$$\pmatrix{x&y}\pmatrix{6&1\\1&2}\pmatrix{x \\ y}=6x^2+2xy+2y^2=5x^2+y^2+(x+y)^2$$

which is $>0$ unless $x=y=0.$

As the quadratic form associated with the given bilinear form is always $>0$ but for the null case, it is associated with a scalar (=dot) product.

Comment: That was a very good explanation, thank you.